# <Error>: CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. in UIimagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, cgaffinetransform

I building app camera use custome overlayview in UIIMagepickercontroller but when I rotate iphone, in console show : CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix. I set

```
imagePicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you mucking about with the `transform` of any view, or the `affineTransform` of any `CALayer`?

Comment: Search this place for "CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix."

Comment: I don't know your idea. @robmayoff

Comment: I typed `uiimagepickercontroller cgaffinetransforminvert` into stack overflow's search box and that was the first result.

Comment: He just wants a personal reply.

Comment: Yes, i have seen it but answer not clear. @robmayoff